# Moment generating function of product of $k$ iid copies of a random variable which is a Rademacher sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, special-functions, generating-functions

Let $X \in [-n,n] \cap \mathbb Z$ be a sum of $n$ iid Rademacher random variables and let $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ be $k \ge 1$ iid copies of $X$, and define the product $Z_k := X_1 X_2 \ldots X_k$. I'm interested in the moment-generating function (MGF) of $Z$, i.e $\eta_k(t) := \mathbb E[e^{-tZ_k}]$. Note that we can write $X = 2B - n$, where $B$ is a Binomial r.v with parameter $n$ and $1/2$. Thus, by marginalizing w.r.t $X_1$, we have

$$
\begin{split}
\eta_k(t) &= \mathbb E_{X_2,\ldots,X_k} \mathbb E_B[e^{-t(2B-n) Z_{k-1}}]= 2^{-n}\sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}\mathbb E_{X_2,\ldots,X_k} [e^{-t(2j-n)Z_{k-1}}]\\
&= 2^{-n}\sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}\eta_{k-1}((2j-n)t).
\end{split}
$$

This gives a recursion formula for $\eta_k(t)$. The base case is $\eta_1(t) = \mathbb E [e^{-tX_1}] = \cosh^n(t)$.

**Question 1.** What is a simple analytic formula for $\eta_k(t)$ (i.e solve the above recursion) ?

**N.B.:** If I knew the generating $z \mapsto G(z,t):=\sum_{k \ge 0} \eta_k(t) z^k$ function of the sequence $(\eta_k(t))_{k \ge 0}$, I could extract it like so: $\eta_k(t) = [z^k] G(z,t)$.

**Question 2.** As a function of $n$ and $t \gt 0$, how fast does $\eta_k(t)$ grow ? If it helps, you may assume $n \ge C \log k$ for some sufficiently large constant $C$. You may even assume $\log n \asymp \log k$. Is $\eta_k(t)$ bounded in any of these regimes ?

Comment: I disagree with the very first lines, where you pull out $e^{tn}$ (neglecting the $Z_{k-1}$ factor). I instead arrive at: $$\eta_k(t)=2^{-n}\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}\eta_{k-1}(t(n-2m))$$I find it unlikely a recursive solution can be found for general $n$. For $n=1$, maybe

Comment: Actually $n=1$ is a trivial case

Comment: Indeed, there is a typo / mistake in first line. Fixed.

Comment: Well, the case $n=1$ is indeed trivial and not very interesting. Indeed, if $R_1,\ldots,R_k$ are iid Rademacher random variables, then their product $R_1R_2 \ldots R_k$ has the same distribution as $R_1$, and therefore $\eta_k(t) = \cosh(t)$ for all $t$ and $k$.

Comment: I’m not sure about “fixed”. Our expressions are still different and you’ve still pulled out $e^{tn}$ on the second line where I believe that is not valid to do. Apologies if I’m mistaken, but for example with $n=1$ your expression predicts $\eta_2(t)=e^t\cosh(t)$ rather than just $\cosh(t)$

Comment: Fixed the stray $e^{tn}$.

Comment: This why you get $\cosh$ in the beginning: Lets say $X_k = R_1 + \ldots + R_n$ with $R_i$ i.i.d. Rademacher distributed. Then $\eta_k (t) = \Bbb E [ e^{-t Z_{k-1} X_k}] = \sum_{z \in \Bbb Z} \Bbb P (Z_{k-1} = z) \Bbb E[e^{-tz (R_1 + \ldots +R_n)}] = \sum_{z \in \Bbb Z} \Bbb P (Z_{k-1} = z) \Bbb (E[e^{-tz R_1}])^n= \sum_{z \in \Bbb Z} \Bbb P (Z_{k-1} = z) \cosh(tz)^n = \Bbb E [\cosh (tZ_{k-1})^n]$

Comment: Yes, earlier I had a similar formula but with the "$e^{tn}$" mistake.